# How to create a batch file to extract information from a file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Someone help me to create a batch file to extract information from a file and create another with that information?

The file "version.log" contains only the information "v1.0"

I want to create a text file with that information "v1.0.txt"

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine:

```
@echo off
set /p VERSION= < version.log
echo "nothing" > "%VERSION%.txt"
```

Comment: Or a `type nul` instead of `echo "nothing"`, if you want an empty file.

Comment: @Bob: Cool. I wanted to write `touch` first, but couldn't come up with the Windows equivalent. Thanks! :)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.
Very very thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

XYZ

```
@echo off
setlocal

set FILE=log.txt
:: Read first line of the file
for /F "tokens=*" %%x in (%FILE%) do (set STR=%%x) && (goto out)
:out
fsutil file createnew %STR% 0
pause 1>nul
```

Comment: `fsutil file createnew %STR%.txt 0`?